# LIT-HTML still use the previous dropdown selected index when rendering a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dom, lit-element, lit-html

I am using Lit-HTML ( NOT Lit-Element ) to build a html form. The form is very simple, it has 2 dropdowns: Population dropdown and Animal dropdown.

The animal dropdown options depends on the selection of the Population dropdown. See the getAnimalDS() logic.

**Model Definition & Utility function:**

```
const model = {
    Population: null,
    Animal: null,
}

const dataSources = {
    Populations: [null, "p1", "p2"],
    Animals_1:   [null, "a1", "a2"],
    Animals_2:   [null, "a3", "a4", "a5"],
}

function getAnimalDS(population) {
    switch (population) {
        case 'p1':
            return dataSources.Animals_1;
        case 'p2':
            return dataSources.Animals_2;
        default:
            return [];
    }
}
```

**The main function to build LIT-HTML template:**

```
function buildSection1(model) {
    return html`
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Population" class="form-label">Population</label>
        <select id="Population" name="Population" class="form-control"
            .value="${model.Population}" @change=${e => {
                            model.Population = e.target.value;
                            model.Animal = null; // Reset Animal
                            renderSection1(); // Re-render the form
                     }}>

            ${dataSources.Populations.map((item) => html`
                    <option value="${item}" ?selected="${model.Population === item}">${item}</option>
            `)}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Animal" class="form-label">Animal</label>
        <select id="Animal" name="Animal" class="form-control"
            .value="${model.Animal}" @change=${e => model.Animal = e.target.value}>

            ${getAnimalDS(model.Population).map((item) => html`
                    <option value="${item}" ?selected="${model.Animal === item}">${item}</option>
            `)}
        </select>
    </div>

    `;
}
```

**TESTING:**

If I select a population on the Population dropdown, I see the options on the Animal get changed correctly -> Awesome.

**STEPS to see issue:**

**#1**: Select option "p1" on the Population dropdown, I see 3 options: "", 'a1', 'a2' on the Animal dropdown -- Good

**#2**: Next, I select 'a2' on the Animal dropdown ( selected index = 2) -> Good

**#3**: Now, select option "p2" on the Population dropdown, I see 4 options: "", 'a3', 'a4', 'a5' on the Animal dropdown -> Good

**#4**: At this point, I expect to see 'EMPTY' line (selected index = -1) on the Animal dropdown , because on @change of the Population, I did reset model.Animal to null.

---- BUT the Animal dropdown shows option 'a4' ( selected index = 2 )

---- It means LIT-HTML uses the previous selected index = 2 at step #2.

Any comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is because lit-html is not aware that the value for the 2nd `<select id="Animal">` element has changed, because the `@change` event handler changes `model.Animal` to `'a2'` but does not call on `render()` again. Since lit-html thinks the value is still `null`, it doesn't bother updating the DOM when re-rendering.

Solution 1: You can fix this by adding `renderSection1()` call there as well like:

```js
html`
  ...
  <select id="Animal" name="Animal" class="form-control"
    .value="${model.Animal}"
    @change=${e => {
      model.Animal = e.target.value;
      renderSection1();
    }}>
  ...
  </select>`
```

which makes lit-html aware that the value has been updated. So when the first dropdown changes the value back to `null` it knows it's different again and update the DOM.

Solution 2: Alternatively, you can also make lit-html always check the value against the DOM value by using the [`live()` directive](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live):

```js
import {live} from 'lit-html/directives/live.js';

html`
  ...
  <select id="Animal" name="Animal" class="form-control"
    .value="${live(model.Animal)}" // always compare against DOM
    @change=${e => model.Animal = e.target.value}>
  ...
  </select>`
```

Comment: Thanks.I will test your solutions this morning.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have a question. If the form has a lot of fields. Should put render method in all @change? or use live for all fields?

Comment: I would prefer to add `render` if you're updating any data that is used by the template to keep it in sync with lit-html parts. I'd resort to `live` when that's not possible. There's a tiny extra work done when using `live` because it'll always check against DOM value.